# update method not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have problem in updating fields in database via codeigniter update method

**My controller:**

```
      $database = array(
        'last_location' => $url[5]."-".$url[6],
        'last_date_location' => $url[3]." ".$url[4],
      );

      $user = $this->API_model->get_user($url[0]);

      print_r($user);

      if ($this->db->update('user', $database , $user['id']) === true) {
        print_r($database);
        echo "MEI_TRUE";
      }else {
        echo "MEI_FALSE";
      }
```

browser return `MEI_TRUE` that mean database successfully updated but when I check database in ***phpmyadmin*** nothing changed :(

what 's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work now.

```
$database = array(
        'last_location' => $url[5]."-".$url[6],
        'last_date_location' => $url[3]." ".$url[4],
      );

      $user = $this->API_model->get_user($url[0]);

      print_r($user);
      $query = $this->db->where('id',$user['id'])
                        ->update('user', $database);
      if ($query) {
        print_r($database);
        echo "MEI_TRUE";
      }else {
        echo "MEI_FALSE";
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like below,

```
$database = array(
        'last_location' => $url[5]."-".$url[6],
        'last_date_location' => $url[3]." ".$url[4],
      );
$this->db->where('id', $user['id']);
$this->db->update('user', $database );
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

the thing is - what do you want to update ?
the 3rd parameter of the update query lets you enable the where clause as a string

although your example is pretty dangerous, try the following

```
if ($this->db->update('user', $database , "id = ".$user['id']) === true) 
{
    print_r($database);
    echo "MEI_TRUE";
}
else 
{
    echo "MEI_FALSE";
}
```

the better way would be (as Dhanesh already mentioned):

```
$blnUpdateSuccess = $this->db->where("id", $user['id'])->update("user",$database);

if ($blnUpdateSuccess) 
{
    print_r($database);
    echo "MEI_TRUE";
}
else 
{
    echo "MEI_FALSE";
}
```

> For more information read the Documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update#updating-data)